# Tkinter: Forget label, update it, appear again?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This a part of a spelling bee program I'm trying to write. I replaced the spelling and definitions with numbers. What I'm trying to make happen is when the correct input is given a label to show up saying 'correct' and a button to appear saying 'next'. When the next button is hit the label that has the definition on should be forgotten, i (the counter thing I'm using) should then increase by 1 and the definition label should appear again, with the next defintion on it, ready to be answered. At the momemt, the definition label disappears then comes back with the same definition and not the next one in the list.

```
from tkinter import *
spelling = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
definition = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
i = 0

gui = Tk()
gui.resizable(0, 0)
app = Frame(gui)
app.grid()
gui.title("test")
gui.geometry("600x400+300+10")

def answercheck():
    global spelling, definition, i
    panswerinput = answerinput.get()
    if spelling[i] == panswerinput:
        if i < 9:
            correctanswer.place(x=310, y=180)
            nextqbutton.place(x=160, y=140)
        else:
            close_window() 
    else:
        wronganswer.place(x=310, y=180)

def nextdefinition():
    global i
    correctanswer.place_forget()
    definitionprint.place_forget()
    i = i + 1
    definitionprint.place(x=310, y=50)
    nextqbutton.place_forget()

# questionlayout widgets
hereisdefinition = Label(bg="white", text="Here is the definition:")
hereisdefinition.config(height=2, width=20)
definitionprint = Label(text=definition[i], fg="yellow", bg="orange")
definitionprint.config(height=2, width=17)
enteranswer = Label(bg="white", text="Please enter your answer:")
enteranswer.config(height=2, width=20)
answerinput = Entry(width=20)
answerenter = Button(text="Enter!", bg="white", command=answercheck)
answerenter.config(height=1, width=17)

# answercheck widgets
wronganswer = Label(fg="red", text="INCORRECT, TRY AGAIN")
correctanswer = Label(bg="green", fg="white", text="CORRECT, WELL DONE")
nextqbutton = Button(text="Next", bg="white", command=nextdefinition)
nextqbutton.config(height=1, width=17)

# starting widgets
hereisdefinition.place(x=160, y=50)
definitionprint.place(x=310, y=50)
enteranswer.place(x=160, y=90)
answerinput.place(x=310, y=100)
answerenter.place(x=310, y=140)

gui.mainloop()
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you asking us to debug your program, or do you have a specific question?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, just my terrible coding skills. And I'm looking for a solution to my problem (above)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use "i", "l" or "O" as single digit variable names as they can look like numbers.  All geometry managers have a "forget" aspect which I think is what you want.  Try the following snippet.  It uses a class which is much easier and straight forward.  Oh, effbot has some links on geometry managers http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

```
class TestQuiz():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gui = Tk()
        self.gui.resizable(0, 0)
        self.gui.title("test")
        self.gui.geometry("600x400+300+10")

        self.label_and_button()

        self.ctr = 0
        self.next_question()
        self.gui.mainloop()

    def answercheck(self):
        print self.answer_var.get()
        print "answercheck, insert check and notify code"
        self.nextqbutton.grid(row=2, column=1) ## reappears
        self.answer_but.grid_forget()     ## disappears

    def label_and_button(self):
        self.answer_label = Label(bg="white", text="Please enter your answer:")
        self.answer_label.config(height=2, width=20)
        self.answer_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.answer_var = StringVar()
        self.answerinput = Entry(width=20, textvariable=self.answer_var)
        self.answerinput.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.answer_but = Button(text="Enter!", bg="white",
                                 command=self.answercheck)
        self.answer_but.config(height=1, width=17)
        self.answer_but.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.nextqbutton = Button(text="Next", bg="white",
                                  command=self.next_question)
        self.nextqbutton.config(height=1, width=17)
        self.nextqbutton.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.nextqbutton.grid_forget()

    def next_question(self):
        self.nextqbutton.grid_forget()     ## disappears
        self.answer_but.grid(row=1, column=0)  ## reappears
        self.answer_label.config(text=str(self.ctr))
        self.answer_var.set("")
        self.ctr += 1

TQ=TestQuiz()
```